# How to pull data into access from an oddly formatted Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a database that needs to pull, and update, customer relations data. One of our departments is given a spreadsheet with info like name, phone #, etc. and I would like to give them a way to one-click (or nearly as efficiently) upload that data to the database we've created.

The problem is that the first ~7 rows contain information that doesn't need to be stored. It's useless as far as the database is concerned. How can I be sure that only the information I want is pulled into the database?

How can I give my colleagues a simple way to update that data? I know it'll likely contain a view, maybe some VBA, but I have minimal to no experience with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import it as is.  Then run the following SQL after you've imported.

```
sql = DELETE FROM (SELECT TOP 7 * FROM TableName)
```

Comment: The thing with this is that when I do a direct import without any prior formatting, it pushes all of the content one column to the right in addition the 7 rows down.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought you just didn't want the first records.  I guess it's like header info that you don't want to import.  Easiest way is to have the data range named in the Excel sheet and use a TransferSpreadsheet command to only import that named range.   But if that requires too much user manipulation, again, just transfer as is and remove the rows as above.  If headings are misaligned then run an update query to SELECT columns/fields you need and recreate the headings properly (to account for the shift).  If it's consistently shifting, then this should work.  Judo that data!

Answer (score 0):

I find the most important thing about creating an automated data import or data mapping process is consistency. If your data is not of a consistent type across all columns from one sheet to the next then creating a dependable automated process is very difficult. However if it is of a consistent type from import to import then it's very possible to do.

The issue that you listed hear sounds like you will have to get into some Excel Automation through Access... as your standard import just isn't going to work in this case by itself. The first thing you would do in the automation process is remove the first 7 rows... then you could perform a standard import.

Normally I would provide a code example of this but am tied up for time this morning. I'm sure a quick search will give you what you need however.